# String editing in data frame not taking effect with .replace code

Tags: python, string, replace

I have two data frames called true and fake. In each, I go to the title column to get rid of any of the characters in my defined grammar list. Somehow, the code below does not work. Can anyone tell me why this code does not get rid of the special characters in the title column?

```
# remove periods and commas from title
grammar = [",", ".", "(", ")", "*", "^", "@", "%", "!", "'", ":", ";"]

## loop over each entry in title column and replace all characters in grammar
for title in true["title"][1:]:
    for c in grammar:
        title = title.replace(c, "")

for title in fake["title"][1:]:
    for c in grammar:
        title = title.replace(c, "")

print(true.head())
# print(true.describe())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for title in true["title"][1:]:
    for c in grammar:
        title = title.replace(c, "")
```

This creates a *new* variable named `title` that has no connection back to its original source.

Try this instead:

```
for i in range(1, len(true["title"])):
    for c in grammar:
        true["title"][i] = true["title"][i].replace(c, "")
```

Comment: Wow, so simple. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done much easier using panda's [string accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) and a translation table:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'title': ['abc, def.', 'gh(ij)']})
grammar = [",", ".", "(", ")", "*", "^", "@", "%", "!", "'", ":", ";"]
tt = str.maketrans('', '', ''.join(grammar))

df.title = df.title.str.translate(tt)
```

Result:

```
     title
0  abc def
1     ghij
```